# Como leer el Response SOAP a nivel de Socket

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Estoy sobre PHP y mediante una conexion cURL estoy recibiendo tramas del tipo SOAP, pero no encuentro la forma de extraer la informacion de interes para despues usarla.

Esto es lo que recibo:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 16:05:50 GMT
Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: Multipart/Related; start-info="text/xml"; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="----=_Part_11693774_xx"
Set-Cookie: TS0133d910=01ca0e1ef6f6e600a5e5f544e580e222d153067bfe4f637ee1fae74f525abcb50681cbd0c3769c51e7a9ab7204cb7a7f2235a061ed; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
------=_Part_11693774_xx
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:header>
        <wsse:security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap-env:mustunderstand="1">
        .... DATA....
        </wsse:security>
    </soap-env:header>
    <soap-env:body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:id="id-11265519">
        .... MAS DATA....
    </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
------=_Part_11693774_xx--
```

Como pueden notar despues de la cabeceras no existe el tipico doble salto de linea (**\n\n**) que basicamente me permite poder extraer los datos y omitir la cabeceras, por lo cual usando **str_ireplace** he logrado estraer cierta parte, pero no toda :(.

Mi objetivo es extraer los datos que estan entre **------=_Part_11693774_xx** y **------=_Part_11693774_xx--**, para despues comvertirlo a XML accesible con **simplexml_load_string()**.

Esto es lo que he codeado:

```
<?php
class Algo{
    private $r=NULL;
    private $data=NULL;

    public function debugResponse() {
        $a= str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:'], '', $this->r);
        $b= '<Data>'. $a. '</Data>';
        $sxml= simplexml_load_string($b);

        print_r($b);
        echo "<br><br>Info..<br>";
        print_r($sxml);
        $this->data= $sxml;
        unset($sxml, $a, $b);
    }

    public function resultado() {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function exec() {
        /* conexion cURL */
        $this->r= curl_exec($s);
        $this->debugResponse();
    }
}

$a= new Algo();
echo 'Datos:<br>'. $a->resultado();
?>
```

Y me retorna:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 16:05:50 GMT
Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: Multipart/Related; start-info="text/xml"; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="----=_Part_11693774_xx"
Set-Cookie: TS0133d910=01ca0e1ef6f6e600a5e5f544e580e222d153067bfe4f637ee1fae74f525abcb50681cbd0c3769c51e7a9ab7204cb7a7f2235a061ed; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
------=_Part_11693774_xx
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
<envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <header>
        <wsse:security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" mustunderstand="1">
        .... DATA....
        </wsse:security>
    </header>
    <body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:id="id-11265519">
        .... MAS DATA....
    </body>
</envelope>
------=_Part_11693774_xx--
```

En este caso la ultima linea **------=_Part_11693774_xx--** no me permite convertirlo a XML, porque ya hice el proceso manual, quite esa ultima linea y ahora si se arma el XML con las partes importantes accesibles.

**---- Editado 12/02/19, 12:49**

He logrado extraer los datos omitiendo las cabeceras, pero curiosamente **simplexml_oad_string()** no me arma el objeto, les dejo código y resultado:

```
<?php
$a= str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:'], '', $this->r);
$pos= stripos($a, "<envelope");
$pos2= stripos($a, "</envelope>")+strlen('</envelope>');
$b= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data>'.substr($a, $pos, ($pos2-$pos)).'</data>';
$sxml= simplexml_load_string($b);
print_r($sxml);
?>
```

Y resultado:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
( [Envelope] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Header] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [Body] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo quedo resuelto, en un principio había implementado una función que me quitaba las etiquetas **Signature** ya que dependiendo el error del SOAP me mandaba distintas etiquetas por lo cual **no resultaba** tan efectiva la solución encontrada en un principio, pero después de darle muchas vueltas caí en la necesidad de que pues ninguna etiqueta me sirve mas que **Body** por lo cual procedí simplemente a cambiar la función por esta que les menciono y me va de maravilla para cualquier tipo de SOAP con o sin Signature recibida en crudo por socket.

```
<?php
class Algo{
    private $r=NULL;
    private $data=NULL;

    public function debugResponse() {
        $a= str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:', ':SOAP-ENV', ':SOAP'], '', $this->r);
        $pos= stripos($a, "<body");
        $pos2= stripos($a, "</body>")+strlen('</body>');
        $b= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Data><Envelope>'.substr($a, $pos, ($pos2-$pos)).'</Envelope></Data>';
        $sxml= simplexml_load_string($b);
        $this->setError($sxml->Envelope->Body->Fault->faultstring ? $sxml->Envelope->Body->Fault->faultstring:NULL);
        $this->setSuccess($sxml->Envelope->Body->Fault->faultstring ? 0:1); # 0=error, 1=exito

        if( strstr($a, "<ns2:Comments") ) {
            # errores de transaccion
            echo '<br><br>-- Errores de Transaccion<br>';
            $t_pos= stripos($a, "<ns2:comments");
            $t_pos2= stripos($a, "</ns2:comments>")+strlen('</ns2:comments>');
            $b2= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Data><Envelope><Body>'.substr($a, $t_pos, ($t_pos2-$t_pos)).'</Body></Envelope></Data>';
            $sxml2= simplexml_load_string($b2);
            print_r($sxml2);
            $this->setError($sxml2->Envelope->Body->Comments ? $sxml2->Envelope->Body->Comments:NULL);
            $this->setSuccess($sxml2->Envelope->Body->Comments ? 0:1);
        }

        unset($sxml, $a, $b);
    }

    public function resultado() {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function exec() {
        /* conexion cURL */
        $this->r= curl_exec($s);
        $this->debugResponse();
    }
}

$a= new Algo();
echo 'Datos:<br>'. $a->resultado();
?>
```